# How to open subnav fullwidth of the website when you hover over the main nav item

Tags: html, css

Im trying to get my subnav to open full width of the website and have everything else blurred out behind the nav when the subnav is open, expect for the title and the main nav of the website.

I tried to set the width for the subnav class to 100% and 100vw, but this only shows the width of the subnav extend fully to the right but not to the left. It looks real awkward. When I scroll down the website I have a class that sets the top nav with a white background. However, when you hover over the menu items with a subnav, the subnav overlaps that main menu. I have attached a pic of this issue.
Actual Results: [Current behaviour/look of the subnav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv7AE.jpg)
Expected Results: [Want it to behave/look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVr9V.png)

HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Garment District</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

  <!-- Bootstrap Font Icon CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navbar -->
  <header class="header">

    <video autoplay loop muted plays-inline class="back-video">
      <source src="videos/Screen Print Halftones Portraits _ a look into Unfinished Legacy.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <div class="nav type-a">
      <nav class="left">
        <ul class="nav-interior">
          <li class="nav-item has-subnav">
            <a href="#">Mens</a>
            <!-- Sub-menu -->
            <div class="sub-nav">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Tops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bottom</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Under Garments</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Womens</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Accesories</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>


      <!-- <img src="images/dist.png" alt="Garment Dist." class="logo"> -->
      <h1 class="logo">Garment Dist.</h1>


      <nav class="right">
        <ul class="nav-interior">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Search</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Bag</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>


    <div class="content">
      <p>Act I</p>
      <!-- <a id="content-link" href="#">Discover</a> -->
    </div>
  </header>


  <main>
    <section class="grid">
      <figure>
        <img src="images/ATHLETHICS.jpg" alt="">
        <figcaption>Mens</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="images/ESSENTIALS.webp" alt="">
        <figcaption>Womens</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="images/FEAROFGOD.webp" alt="">
        <figcaption>Accessories</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </section>
  </main>


  <!-- Footer  -->

  <footer>
    <div class="footer-content">
      <div class="newsletter">
        <img src="images/dist.png">
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-footer">
        <li class="nav-footer-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="nav-footer-item"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="nav-footer-item"><a href="#">Legal Notices</a></li>
        <li class="nav-footer-item"><a href="#">Socials</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <!-- JavaScript Files -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;

}

body {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTPro-Cn', arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

div,
a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* NAV CSS */
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 4.53125vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 1;
}

.type-a {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  font-weight: 500;
}


.sticky {
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  transition: 400ms ease-in-out;
}

.sticky ul a,
.sticky h1 {
  color: black;
}

.header .logo {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 90px;
  min-height: 15px;
}

.left .nav-interior .nav-item {
  margin-right: 1.875vw;
  position: relative;
}

.right .nav-interior .nav-item {
  margin-left: 1.875vw;
  position: relative;

}

.back-video {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .back-video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .back-video {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 5.9375vw;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  letter-spacing: -.02em;
  font-family: Optima, Optima, sans-serif;

}

#content-link {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.90vw;
}


h1.logo {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

/* Footer CSS */

footer {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.footer-content {
  padding: 50px;
  display: block;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
  width: auto;
}

.nav-footer {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 0.72vw;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.nav-footer-item a {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 1.875vw;
  list-style: none;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.newsletter {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}

.newsletter img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

/* Main Section CSS */
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Optima, Optima, sans-serif;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 4vw;
  display: flex;
  font-family: inherit;
}


.left {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}

.right {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-interior {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
}

.right .nav-interior {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

nav {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
}

nav ul,
nav ol,
nav li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav .nav-interior {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.52083vw 0;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  font-family: 'HelveticaPro';
}

/* Hover Effects CSS */

.nav-item a:hover,
.nav-footer-item a:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  transition: opacity .2s ease;
}

.sub-nav {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  /* Position below the parent */
  /* Expand full width */
  left: 0;
  backdrop-filter: blur(30px);
  width: 100vw;
}


.sub-nav ul {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sub-nav a:hover {
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.has-subnav:hover .sub-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 40vw;
}

.nav-item {
  position: relative;
}
```